# Single width bootstrap gutters

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

In Bootstrap 3, the container has padding of 1/2 the gutterwidth, and each column has spacing of 1 gutterwidth (1/2 from each column). This means the spacing between the individual columns is not consistent with the gutters on the side of the site.

If you assume 15px gutters, then you get 15px spacing on the outermost container and then 30px between each column.

What is the best way to modify BS so that the spacing between each column is also 15px, rather than 30px?

I assume I can change the mixins (using SCSS) for grid and grid-framework but this then impacts on the rest of the grid.

This currently looks like:
|15px| COL 1 |30px| COL 2 |30px| COL 3 |15px|

I want:

|15px| COL 1 |15px| COL 2 |15px| COL 3 |15px|

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
row [class*="col-"]+[class*="col-"]{
     padding-left: 0;
 }
```

Comment: try this
row [class*="col-"]+[class*="col-"]{
     padding-left: 0;
 }